# preg_replace: unknown modifier

Tags: php, preg-replace

Let's assume that $body is equal to

```
something 
that 
does 
not 
interest 
me 
<!-- start -->
some
html
code
<!-- end -->
something
that
does
not
interest
me
```

If I use

```
$body=preg_replace("(.*)<!-- start -->(.*)<!-- end -->(.*)","$2",$body);
```

I obtain:

> Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier '<'

How have I to correct?

Comment: It probably would be easier to get the position of *start* and the position of *end* with `strpos` and then get just the part between these positions with `substr`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[Warning: preg\_replace(): Unknown modifier '\]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20705399/warning-preg-replace-unknown-modifier)* (same reason, missing regular expression delimiters)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A `preg` pattern needs a pair of characters which delimit the pattern itself. Here your pattern is enclosed in the first pair of parentheses and everything else is outside.

Try this:

```
$body=preg_replace("/(.*)<!-- start -->(.*)<!-- end -->(.*)/","$2",$body);
```

This is just about the syntax, and there is no guarantee on the pattern itself which looks suspicious.

Assuming the text in your example:

```
preg_match('#<!-- start -->(.*?)<!-- end -->#s', $text, $match);
$inner_text = trim($match[1]);
```

Comment: replacing " " with "$2" solves the issue. Still I have a question,  using $2 will it affect any other area?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$body = preg_replace("/(.*)<!-- start -->(.*)<!-- end -->(.*)/","$2",$body);
```